# Proof of there is only one $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\Bbb{Q}^Z$ be composition of all $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $\Bbb{Q}$, which is defined as galois extension over $\Bbb{Q}$ whose galois group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_p$ as an abelian group.

I encountered an argument which says

> A fact ' $\text{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}^Z/\Bbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_p$ '
> implies  there is only one $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $\Bbb{Q}$.

I cannot follow this argument.
Why $\text{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}^Z/\Bbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_p$ '
implies  there is only one $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $\Bbb{Q}$ ?

P.S
My question is

> Why $\text{Gal}(\Bbb{Q}^Z/\Bbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_p$ '
> implies  there is only one $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $\Bbb{Q}$ ?

Can anybody follow this logic(not asking the titled question's proof except for this logic) ?

Comment: Isomorphic as topological group. Every non-trivial continuous quotient of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is a finite group $\Bbb{Z}_p/(p^k)$. So every subfield of $\Bbb{Q}^Z$ is a number field.

Comment: Could you tell me why does that imply there is only one $\Bbb{Z}_p$- exntension over $\Bbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: A $\mathbb Z_p$-extension of $\mathbb Q$ must in particular contain $\mathbb Z/p^n \mathbb Z$-extensions for each $n$, since these groups are continuous quotients of $\mathbb Z_p$.  But there is only one such $\mathbb Z/p^n \mathbb Z$-extension for each $n$, and their union is all of $\mathbb Q^Z$.

Comment: @RaviFernando your comment can be misread as saying $\mathbf Q$ has a unique extension with Galois group $\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$, which would be incorrect. There are infinitely many primes $q \equiv 1 \bmod p^n$, and inside each of the different fields $\mathbf Q(\zeta_q)$, which all pairwise intersect in $\mathbf Q$, there is a subfield whose Galois group over $\mathbf Q$  is cyclic of order $p^n$. So the "only one such" field you refer to that is cyclic of order $p^n$ is not unique just for being cyclic of order $p^n$, but for being cyclic of order $p^n$ *inside a* $\mathbf Z_p$-extension.

Answer (score 3):

Every finite abelian extension of $\mathbf Q$ lies in a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbf Q$, so if ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbf Q) \cong \mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$ then $K \subset \mathbf Q(\zeta_m)$ for some $m$. A number field inside a $\mathbf Z_p$-extension of $\mathbf Q$ is ramified only at $p$, and the subfields of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_m)$ that are ramified only at $p$ lie inside $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{p^r})$, where $p^r$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $m$. Therefore $K$ is a subfield of a $p$-power cyclotomic extension of $\mathbf Q$.

For all $p$ the Galois group ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf Q(\zeta_{p^r})/\mathbf Q)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbf Z/p^r\mathbf Z)^\times$ and has order $\varphi(p^r) = p^{r-1}(p-1)$.  When $p \not= 2$ this group is cyclic, so $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{p^r})$ has a unique (cyclic) subextension of $\mathbf Q$ of each $p$-power degree that divides $p^{r-1}$. Since the fields $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{p^r})$ as $r$ grows form an increasing tower, each layer of a $\mathbf Z_p$-extension of $\mathbf Q$ has only one possibility.  Therefore there is at most one $\mathbf Z_p$-extension of $\mathbf Q$.  Since we know how to create at least one $\mathbf Z_p$-extension of $\mathbf Q$ (the cyclotomic $\mathbf Z_p$-extension), this extension exists and is unique.

For $p \not= 2$ the argument needs a little more work since $(\mathbf Z/2^r\mathbf Z)^\times$ is not cyclic when $r \geq 3$. Layers of a $\mathbf Z_2$-extension are ramified only at $2$, so these layers are inside the maximal real subfield $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{2^r})^+$, as this is the subfield fixed by complex conjugation: subfields unramified at the Archimedean place are contained in this subfield. The extension $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{2^r})^+/\mathbf Q$ is cyclic of degree $2^{r-1}$, so we can run through the same argument as above to see $\mathbf Q$ has a unique $\mathbf Z_2$-extension.

Comment: It might be worth to add that from the point of view of class field theory the cyclotomic extensions $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^n})$ are precisely the extension of conductor $p^n\infty$, hence their totally real subfields are the extension of conductor $p^n$. One can show that in any $\mathbb Z_p$-extension at most $p$ ramifies giving an alternative access to the overall question.

Comment: @mrtaurho your comment that "in any $\mathbf Z_p$-extension at most $p$ ramifies" is something I said in the first paragraph, and that is how for instance we can decide which of the cyclic $2$-power extensions inside $\mathbf Q(\zeta_{2^r})$ can be subfields of a $\mathbf Z_2$-extension of $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: Ah, I've seem to have overlooked that part. I'll keep my comment, though, expanding on this first paragraph if you don't mind.

Comment: @mrtaurho fair enough, that comment can get lost in the whole answer.  I initially considered giving a shorter answer to emphasize the main point in the first paragraph, but then decided to expand things a little bit.

Comment: Is this actually answering the question? I thought the actual question was: *given that the Galois group of the compositum of all $\mathbf{Z}_p$-extensions of $\mathbf{Q}$ is $\mathbf{Z}_p$, show that there is only one such extension* which is an elementary statement about groups (and how Galois theory works), rather than your answer. (That is, you answer the question stated in the title, but what the OP actually wants to understand the simpler statement given here. I admit I'm not 100% I'm correct about the OPs desires, however.

Comment: @user994373 yes, I was answering the question in the title.  I found it hard to parse what was going on in the post itself, but the title was concise, so I went with addresses what is asked in the title.